# mongodb: query for values (not objects) in list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I have a database with documents like

```
{_id: 5,
 fruit: 'apple',
 vitamins: ['B1', 'B12', 'A1']
}
{_id: 7,
 fruit: 'appricot',
 vitamins: ['B6', 'D12', 'A1']
}
```

Is there a way to query for all the records which have e.g. vitamin 'A1'?

I am looking for a mongo shell query and a pymongo equivalent.
I know that I can put a for loop to iterate over records and check whether the list contains an element or no, but I prefer a query if there is one.

As it is a list and not a list of objects so seems I can't use $elemMatch...

Thanks

Comment: A simple find query like `db.collection.find({"vitamins":"A1"})` should work just fine.  Did you try it?

Comment: of course I did, it doesn't work...
With the query you wrote, I expect to get the records which have `"vitamins":"A1"`, exactly "A1" and nothing more.

Comment: Got it.  You have 2 options: 1) Use the index in the projection like `db.collection.find({"vitamins":"A1"}, {"fruit":1, "vitamins.$":1})` 2) Aggregation framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

**Option 1:** If you want to match just one element, you could use the index in projection

```
db.collection.find({"vitamins":"A1"}, {"fruit":1, "vitamins.$":1})
```

**Option 2:** If you want to able to match multiple elements in the array, you can look at the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$vitamins"}, {$match:{"vitamins":"A1"}}])
```

Comment: Thanks @Anand!
Tried Option 1, works fine. Still need to read more about the aggregation framework, I don't yet understand it properly.